# Matrix gradient descent method with power constraints

Tags: optimization, numerical-methods, lagrange-multiplier, numerical-optimization, gradient-descent

I'm solving an optimization problem
\begin{equation}
  \begin{aligned}\label{}
    & \underset{A\in \mathbb{R}_{m,d_1} B\in \mathbb{R}_{n,d_2}}{\text{minimize}}
    & & \phi({A},B) \\
    & \text{subject to}
    & & \|Ha_j\|_2^2=1 , \ j = 1, \ldots, d_1.\\
    &&& \|Vb_j\|_2^2=1 , \ j = 1, \ldots, d_2. 
  \end{aligned}
\end{equation}
where $H$ and $V$ are known matrices, $a_j$'s and $b_j$'s are columns of $A$ and $B$
I can't solve the optimal solution, so I try to use numerical methods like gradient descent
But I don't know how to use gradient descent with such constraint
I already have derivative of  $\phi$ w.r.t. to  $A$ and $B$
My thought is to seek the matrix $A'$ in the constraint set which has the smallest distance (like Frobenius norm) to $A_{k+1}^{temp} = A_k- \alpha_k\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial A}(A_k,B_k)$ to be $A_{k+1}$and follow the similar way to update $B$.
That is, solve
\begin{equation}
  \begin{aligned}\label{}
    & \underset{A\in \mathbb{R}_{m,d_1} }{\text{minimize}}
    & & \|A-A_{k+1}^{temp}\|_F^2 \\
    & \text{subject to}
    & & \|Ha_j\|_2^2=1 , \ j = 1, \ldots, d_1.\\ 
  \end{aligned}
\end{equation}
Am I on the right way to constrainted gradient descent?
Any help would be appreciated!

Refer to Rem's answer, BFGS may work better. But how BFGS work on matrix variable and under some constraints?

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to look at the dual problem. Introduce a penalty in your cost function and solve a bigger but easier problem instead. See [Duality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duality_(optimization)#Linear_case), [Lagrange multiplier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier).

The idea is solve a new, unconstrained problem, namely find a saddle point of:
$$L(A,B,\lambda,\mu) = \phi(A,B) - \sum_{j=1}^{d1}\lambda_j(\lVert Ha_j\rVert^2-1) - \sum_{j=1}^{d2}\mu_j(\lVert Vb_j\rVert^2-1)$$

Comment: Yes, I have tried that and found that I can't solve it analytically. How do I determine $\lambda$'s in gradient descent if I just run gradient descent with $L$?

Comment: And $\lambda_1$, $\lambda_2$ should be vectors instead of scalars.

Comment: You don't run a gradient descent to find a saddle point. Gradient descents slow down dramatically near a saddle point but (I think) will eventually get away from it. You would need other algorithm to solve this. A (quasi-)Newton method like BFGS maybe?

Comment: why we are going to find a saddle point?

Comment: Can you show me some details about how BFGS works?

Comment: [BFGS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Broyden%E2%80%93Fletcher%E2%80%93Goldfarb%E2%80%93Shanno_algorithm). It is widely used in machine learning, so there should be plenty of explanation of how it works available online. We find a saddle point because of how the constraint is imposed in the new functional $L$. Check the Wikipedia page of Lagrange Multiplier, in the "single constraint" tab.

Comment: But most of them are used in the situation the target variable is a vector,  in my case, the variable is a matrix, how to extend the method to matrix case? Also, most are unconstrainted, how to extend to constrained case? sorry, I haven't learned about this method.

Comment: A matrix can be rearranged into a vector. Check out [these slides](https://wsc.project.cwi.nl/woudschoten-conferences/2012-woudschoten-conference/Benzi1.pdf) for how to solve.